# Regex: How to create an array of objects from all matches in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting

I'm trying to get a string input like this:

```
{p}This is a paragraph{/p} {img}(path/to/image) {p}Another paragraph{/p}
```

To return an array of objects like this

```
[
  {"txt" : "This is a paragraph" },
  {"img" : "path/to/image"},
  {"txt" : "Another paragraph"}
]
```

I need the array to be indexed by the order they are found – i.e. in the example above the first paragraph gets index 0, image gets index 1 and so forth.

I can get the strings great with the code below, but I am unsure how to modify it to loop through the entire string and put together the object. So any pointers would be greatly appreciated

```
var p = /{p}(.*){\/p}/gmi;
var i = /{img}\((.*)\)/gmi;

var test = "{p} This is a paragraph {/p} {img}(text)";


function returnJson(test) {
  var ps = p.exec(test);
  var im = i.exec(test)
  var arr = [];
  if (ps.length > 1) {
    arr.push({"txt" : ps[1]})
  } 
  if (im.length > 1) {
    arr.push({"img" : im[1]})
  }
  return arr;
}
```

I was thinking of doing a recursive function, where I replace the found matches with the string. But then I am unsure of how to get the array in the order they were found. Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you only dealing with paragraphs and images?

Comment: I will have one or two more elements – most likely headings and links that will be marked in a similar fashion.

Comment: Will they both close like the paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, i was thinking `{h}Heading{/h}` and `{a}Link Text{/a}(url)`. I am setting the markup of the strings myself, so I'm very flexible when it comes to altering the structure.

Comment: And will they ever be nested? Or will links always be siblings to paragraphs instead of children of them?

Comment: I am generating the final string from a database table containing different identifiers like `[intro]` which in turn contains a string like `This is the introduction. You have chosen [alternative] which means that you are [likelihood] to...".` These are nested, but once all those identifiers are fetched, the final string with the bracket markup should only contain siblings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this regex

```
/{(\w+)}([^{]+)(?:{\/\1})?/g
```

And create an array using `exec` like this:

```js
let str = "{p}This is a paragraph{/p} {img}(path/to/image) {p}Another paragraph{/p}";

let regex = /{(\w+)}([^{]+)(?:{\/\1})?/g;
let match;
let matches = [];

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    if(match[1] == "p")
      matches.push({ txt: match[2] })
    else
      matches.push({ [match[1]]: match[2]})
}

console.log(matches)
```

- `{(\w+)}` gets the tag name to a capturing group
- `([^{]+)` gets the content to another capturing group
- `(?:{\/\1})?` optionally matches the closing tag. (`\1` refers to the first capturing group)

Comment: Very close! There's parens around the image path that need to be removed, and a trailing space.

Comment: Thank you! Clever idea with the while-loop and using the different capture groups to add to the array. I modified the expression to `{(\w+)}(?:\()?([^{[\)]+)(?:\))?(?:{\/\1})?` to exclude a leading parenthesis and not match the ending parenthesis. This looks like it should work? I am new to these more complex regex patterns, so sorry if it is obvious

Comment: @user2868900 I didn't see the parenthesis bit. That should work: https://regex101.com/r/TMRVG8/1